# Seamlessly change all desktop spaces' wallpaper on Mac without killall Dock

Tags: macos, applescript, dock, desktop, spaces

I would like to change the wallpaper on ALL desktops including spaces on Mac but without needing to call `killall Dock` each minute. (Dock restarting forces wallpaper refresh).

I have an AppleScript that changes the desktop wallpaper instantly:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell every desktop to set picture to wallpaperPath
```

but that only changes the wallpaper on the active space (meaning that if the main desktop is not active, its background will not change).

I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185506/how-to-loop-through-all-mac-desktop-spaces which suggests updating wallpaper path values in the SQLite database located at `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`. This changes the wallpaper at every space which is great but it requires restart of the dock using `killall Dock` which is undesirable as it disrupts the workflow.

My question is - is there some way to combine these two approaches? Seamlessly change wallpapers on every desktop space?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have no preferred language, it can be in C, Swift, Python, Bash, AppleScript etc.

Comment: When you say "each minute" - does that mean you want to continually change the desktop at a set interval?

Comment: Do not cross post the same question on multiple **Stack Exchange** sites. You posted the the same question on **Stack Overflow** yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412058/seamlessly-change-all-desktop-spaces-wallpaper-on-mac-without-killall-dock

Comment: I want to change the desktop wallpaper each whole minute.

Comment: Yes I asked the question on SO but I only got a downvote and no answer so I figured I will ask it here. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I am looping through all available screens and setting the wallpaper using [setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1527228-setdesktopimageurl?language=objc) (based on Graham Miln's answer):

```
for screen in NSScreen.screens {
    try! NSWorkspace.shared.setDesktopImageURL(url, for: screen, options: [:])
}
```

This changes the wallpapers seamlessly, without the need for `killall Dock` on all the screens but only if the desktop is the active space.

To make sure the wallpaper is changed when I am on another space (usually a fullscreen app), I added an observer for `NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification` on the `NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter` which sets the desktop images again (using the code above). So whenever I go back to the desktop, this notification is invoked and the wallpaper is seamlessly updated.

I even went one step further and added the same observer also for the `NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification` which updates the wallpaper as soon as the device wakes up which is cool!

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) and the [setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1527228-setdesktopimageurl?language=objc) method:

> ```
> setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:
> ```
>
> Sets the desktop image for the given screen to the image at the specified URL.

This API is accessible through Objective-C and Swift. I presume scripting bridges for `python` can also access these methods.

See the links below for other approaches using AppleScript:

- [Changing the background image in all spaces](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98224/changing-the-background-image-in-all-spaces)
- [Can I have a custom desktop wallpaper 'Change Picture' interval?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103833/can-i-have-a-custom-desktop-wallpaper-change-picture-interval)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions however the above method does not work the way I wanted. It only changes the wallpaper on the screen if I am on the desktop (and not in a fullscreen app in another space).

As for the links you provided below - the first one is very obtrusive since it switches between spaces (I want a seamless wallpaper change in the background). The second one is not exactly what you want since it's interval based and I want to be able to change it at any desired time, not necessarily in intervals.